# How can I create list from elements of another list

Tags: python, list

Please help me I got stuck in something that seems quite simple. I just want to create list from elements of another list. I can do it this way but cant figure out faster way because my list has around 500 elements and I dont want to write list name 500 times. Example :

```
testing = [ 'john', 'mark', 'joseph', 'cody', 'bill' , 'dick']
new= [testing [0], testing[3], testing[4]]
```

gives me what I want, but how can I make it faster. I tried

```
new = [testing ([0], [3], [4])]
```

and get `'list' object is not callable`

Answer (score 5):

For the specific case of not re-writing the list name

```
indices = [0, 3, 4]
new = [testing[i] for i in indices]
```

will work. When you write

```
[testing ([0], [3], [4])]
```

You are writing `testing(...)`. When python sees these parentheses, it thinks you are trying to call a function, which is why it says `list object not callable`.

There is also slicing notation like

```
testing[a:b:step]
```

to take the elements starting at `a` until (and not including) `b` in step sizes of `step`, but in your case you might have to take the more general approach given above where you just supply the indices yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I am aware of slicing but needed it like this

Comment: Of course, if you don't really want/need  to factor out the list of indices, just use: `new = [testing[i] for i in [0, 3, 4]]`